# Show Null if count is 0

Tags: mysql, null

I have the following query:

```
 SELECT e.employeeName, DATE_FORMAT(`maintenanceDate`, "%M %Y") AS
    Month,count(`maintenanceID`) AS Total  
    FROM `maintenance` m join employee e  
    on m.employeeID =e.employeeID  
    group by month,e.employeeID
```

which generates the result like this

```
employeeName    Month   Total
Big             Apr-15  2
Bar             Dec-14  1
Big             Dec-14  1
```

May I know how it can be improve so that the query will show a total of 0 for each employee that does not have a count in that particular month? 
Eg: bar will have total 0 in April 2015

Comment: do right join instead of join

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a list of all employees and months and then bring in the data that you want to count.  The complete lists uses a `cross join`.  Then use `left join` to get the rest of the data:

```
select e.employeeName, mon.Month, count(m.maintenanceID) AS Total  
from employee e cross join
     (select distinct date_format(maintenanceDate, '%M %Y') as month
      from maintenance
     ) mon left join
     maintenance m   
     on m.employeeID = e.employeeID and 
        date_format(m.maintenanceDate, '%M %Y') = mon.month
group by m.month, e.employeeID;
```